# Open links on a webpage saved in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON file which store links to images. How can I view these images in a webpage?

A similar [JSON file](https://jpst.it/1fVmg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this. For my solution you will have to use jQuery.

First you will need to load the json file:

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(json) {
    urlList = json; 
});
```

Since JS natively supports json you don't have to parse the file and can iterate directly through it:

```
for (key in urllist){
    url = urllist[key].image;
    $('#images').append('<img src="' + url + '" />')
}
```

This will add an image for every entry into an HTML-Element with the ID "images".